# Using javascript to call controller method in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to make a table row work as a link to another view in my mvc website. Instead of using the standard "Details" link provided by the auto generated table list, I would like to use the table row as a link to the "Details" view instead. So somehow I need to make the row work as a link. Each rom has a unique id that I need to pass on to the controller method. I have tried different solutions but noting happens when I press on the table row...

So far this is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#customers tr').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "Customer/Details" + id,
            succes: function () { }
        });
    })
})
</script>
```

My controller method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    Customer model = new Customer();
    model = this.dbEntities.Customers.Where(c => c.Customer_ID == id).Single();
    return View(model);
}
```

Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }     
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "CustomerDetails",
        "Customer/Details/{id}",
        new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", id = "" }
    );
}

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Comment: Check This: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Multiple-ways-to-call-Controller-Action-Method-from-a-Razor-View

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
<tr data-id='@SomeRazorDataId' class="MyAction">foo</tr>
```

And then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.MyAction').live("click",function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        window.location = "Customer/Details/" + id;
    })
});
```

If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you should use the `on()` method rather than the `live()` method.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks :) Got it working by simply using window.location = "Details/" + id;

Comment: Great!  Now don't forget to set your style for the row with a pointer: `.MyAction{cursor:pointer;}`.  Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a *typo* in your code;

```
success:
//----^
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1. Add a **slash** (`/`) between the action and the parameter: `url: "Customer/Details/" + id`, otherwise, you'll invoke an `Action` called `Details123`, for example, which doesn't exist;
2. Make sure you have a configured **route** in your Global.asax to support the `id`, i.e., `Customer/Details/{id}`:
3. Like @undefined said, the name of the callback is **`success`**, not `succes`.

Your `Global.asax` should have something along these lines:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "CustomerDetails",
  "Customer/Details/{id}",
  new { controller = "Customer", action = "Details", id = ""}
);
```

Comment: Thanks!
1. Done!
2. Done!
3. What?? How to?

Comment: @ChristianThoressonDahl: What does your Global.asax look like?

Comment: @ChristianThoressonDahl: Please check my update and add the new route.

Comment: Updated my post with the new route in global.asax. Still not working. I must have done something else wrong... After spending hours in front of the computer I would not be surprised if its just a little stupid thing... :)

Comment: @ChristianThoressonDahl: Your route is wrong, it's not `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, it's `Customer/Details/{id}`.

Comment: updated global.asax. Still not working... So far thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this type of situation lately and opted to use the Ajax helper class:

```
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "Details", 
        new
        {
            id = Model.Id
        }, null)
```

In this example it would assume that you want a link saying 'details' and you're already in the Customer controller.

Either way, look at the helper classes if all you want to do is fire a controller action from a link, gives you a bit more strong typing in terms of how to pass/handle the id value etc

Answer (score 0):

The url that you have tried to call is invalid:

"Customer/Details" + id,

instead it should be **"Customer/Details&id=" + id**

(OR)

use 'data'

$.ajax({
                url: "Customer/Details",
                data:{id:id},
                succes: function () { }
            });